# How to pass form data as part of request payload in cypress API testing

Tags: cypress

I have a payload that is in the form-data format which looks like this in Postman
[image: Postman request format]

I need to pass this data using Cypress to automate this API endpoint

```
let doc_orderId = null;
    let documentNumber = 'AVBBBBB3';
    
    cy.fixture('onFileDocPost').then(onFileDocPost => {
        doc_orderId = onFileDocPost.doc_orderId;
                

            cy.request({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: url + onFileUrl + onFilePostUrl,
                    auth: {
                        'bearer': Cypress.env('token')
                        },
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Bearer token'
                    },
                    form: true,
                    body: {
                        OrderId : 11822104127,
                        RawResponse: 'cypress/fixtures/TestFile.png',
                        SearchQuery:  {documentNumber},
                        ExtractionDateUtc: "2023-06-09T06:22:00Z"
                    }

            })
```

So i am not sure if its the right way of passing the form-data. I get the below error even though that field is there in the payload.
[image: Error]

Could someone help me with this, as the field is already there. Is it expecting in a particular format. Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

I could resolve this issue in the following way. I used formdata.append to address this issue
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).